# I have 50 fields, Is there any option in pig to print first 40 field in Apache Pig? I require something like range $0-$39

Tags: apache-pig

I have 50 fields, Is there any option in pig to print first 40 fields? I require something like range $0-$39. 
I don’t want to specify each and every field like $0, $1,$2 etc

Giving every column when the number of columns is less is acceptable but when there are a huge number of columns what is the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `..` notation.

First 40 fields

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0..$39;
```

All fields

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0..;
```

Multiple ranges,for example first 10,15-20,25-50

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0..$9,$14..$19,$24..;
```

Random fields 22,33-44,46

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $21,$32..$43,$45;
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info