# Apache pig How to select all columns from one relation when performing a join operation

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have two relations:

Relation1:

```
Col1......Col100, id
```

Relation2:

```
R2Col1, R2Col2, R2Col3, id
```

Now I am trying to do something like:

```
Relation3 = Join Relation 1 BY id, Relation2 BY id USING 'replicated';
```

In this case relation3 will become:
Relation 3:

```
Col1......Col100, id, R2Col1, R2Col2, R2Col3, id
```

I am wondering if there's a way to select columns from relation 1 only. There's many columns so it's not ideal to hardcode them. Ideally I am looking for something equivalent the `SELECT relation1.*` in SQL. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use positional notation with `..` to get all the fields from relation 1.`$0..` means generate all fields starting from the first field $0. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051846/i-have-50-fields-is-there-any-option-in-pig-to-print-first-40-field-in-apache-p/47057547#47057547), I've answered a similar question.

```
relation4 = foreach relation3 generate relation1::$0..;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it's giving me an error : `[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 20, column 97>  mismatched input '..' expecting SEMI_COLON` ?

Comment: @Rockingchief Post your entire script.